# Result of summing std::valarray differs when changing optimization levels

Tags: c++, optimization, valarray

I have this piece of code summing `std::valarray<int>`'s:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::valarray<int>> vectorOfValarrays{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
    std::valarray<int> sumOfValarrays(2);
    for (const auto& i : vectorOfValarrays)
      sumOfValarrays = sumOfValarrays + i;

    std::cout << sumOfValarrays[0] << ' ' << sumOfValarrays[1];
}
```

Compiling with `x86-64 gcc 12.2` using [`-O0`](https://godbolt.org/z/f1YMMGh1q) and [`-O1`](https://godbolt.org/z/6ME914jT7), it prints the expect result:

```
6 6
```

But when compiling with [`-O2`](https://godbolt.org/z/fhTxz1cEW) and [`-O3`](https://godbolt.org/z/PczzqhMj6), it prints:

```
3 3
```

What could be the reason for this? Is my code undefined behaviour or is this a gcc bug?

Comment: Add `-fno-tree-vectorize` and you get `3 6`. IMO it's a gcc bug.

Comment: Fwiw: clang and icx both say `6` no matter the optimization level. I think @273K is on to something.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/valarray) valarray constructor (2) value-initializes its elements so if it's UB, it's not obvious why.

Comment: Sounds like a [weird](https://godbolt.org/z/WEMve1G69) bug.

Comment: Hi, does it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861540/is-the-glibcxx-stl-incorrect-in-its-implementation-of-stdvalarraysum?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is a gcc bug. Clang gives the correct behaviour for all optimization levels ([`-O0`](https://godbolt.org/z/ExdW1x7bh), [`-O1`](https://godbolt.org/z/MMv9Eef4c), [`-02`](https://godbolt.org/z/d8zMdK99E), [`-O3`](https://godbolt.org/z/G41b8MbKW)). I also have a look at `std::valarray` [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/valarray), [operator +](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith3) and [operator =](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator%3D) and it seems like my code doesn't any undefined behaviour.

I found [this bug report on gcc Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=99117), and the problem seems like gcc has the wrong implementation for copying `std::valarray`, so in the question the line `sumOfValarrays = sumOfValarrays + i;` makes gcc tripped up.